# How to delete a registry key only if it has no values or subkeys using a *.bat file?

Tags: batch-file, registry

Problem is that I want to delete registry key only if no subkeys or values are present and I want to accomplish this using *.bat file. I have not found any viable solution. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Why does it *have* to be a batch file?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe It would be the most preferable way, but it not required actually. So any solution would be great as long as I would be able to run program as ghost app.

Comment: What do you mean by "ghost app"? At this point, I'd normally reach for some PowerShell, but that may not be appropriate to your problem.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe By ghost app I mean program which is not visible by user, runs in background.

Comment: A batch file will have the CMD window open - not what you want.   I hope this is not a malicious app.  Requests that want hidden operations always make me nervous.

Comment: I use Quick BFC to compile exe which launches different executable, but before it launches I need some things renamed, moved and I need to edit registry, but after it closes I need to delete registry key only if there are no values there left. Nothing malicious, program is for myself anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way to do this with Windows system commands, but your fastest route may be to write a simple console application to accept a key as an argument and then check for child nodes, removing those without any.  Then call it from the batch file.  If this is feasible, I can post some C# code to do the trick.

EDIT

Here is simple C# code for a console program which can be run to delete a key, as long as it is empty.  It uses HKEY_CURRENT_USER but can easily be modified to access HKEY_LOCALMACHINE as well.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace RegistryKeyDelete
{
   class Program
   {
      static int Main(string[] args)
      {
         const int EXIT_SUCCESS = 0;
         const int EXIT_FAILURE = 1;

         if (args.Length < 1)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

         RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(args[0]);
         if (registryKey == null || registryKey.SubKeyCount != 0 || registryKey.ValueCount != 0)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

         try {
            Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey(args[0], true);
         } catch {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
         }

         return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      }
   }
}
```

Build it as RegistryKeyDelete and use it like this in the batch file:

```
RegistyKeyDelete Software\MyEmptyKey
```

If you want it to walk and parse the registry under a path, you can start with the above code and then enumerate the keys and check each one.  I'm assuming you already know which keys you are checking.

BTW - Standard disclaimer when doing anything with the registry: use caution and backup.

Comment: It's not the most perfect solution, but I will take what I can get. If you could write code, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple Powershell script

Assume that you have the following regkey ExtensionInstallForceList at:
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\

If you want to delete the regkey when empty you could use the next code.
When the regkey is empty (besides the Default value) the key 'ExtensionInstallForceList'  is deleted, if any value exist the key is not deleted.

```
# Remove regkey if empty
$remove = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForceList 
if (-not $remove) {
Remove-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForceList -Force
}
```

If you want to run the powershell script without windows you could use a vbs script

```
command = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File regkey-delete.ps1"
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command,0
```